# Why has MediaWiki still no WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: mediawiki

After almost 10 years, MediaWiki still has no support for a WYSIWYG editor. The [metapage](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/WYSIWYG_editorexpressions.) explaining various info about this topic states that

> The problem is that any WYSIWYG editor would have to know wikitext grammar, and no full grammar for wikitext exists - the "parser" doesn't parse, it's a twisty series of regular expressions.

So - is it technically impossible, or no successfull effort has been made to specify the grammar?

Comment: Well, for one thing, it's near impossible to make one that would understand any markup language more than a human can. Another that when you think of it, better formatted source makes for better formatted results. Think of Daring Fireball vs. a typical Blogger blog.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying here.

Comment: Ok, try playing around with Google Sites for a few minutes. If you start making a table and make a list in it, or something else equally complicated and long, it starts to slow down. If you see the HTML source, the source is as heck as spaghetti-y. This is all solved if you are forced to make everything good from the source.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing (well, almost nothing) is technically impossible, it is more than likely that the majority of people who do the editing know the commands off by heart and simply do not need it, therefore, the cost/time of development does not outweigh the benefits of having it.